# Change class name by tag name

Tags: javascript

There is a line of code which couldn't work. I use these codes to change class name by window width. Thank you!

```
<script>
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

  function waddonsclass() {
    td[0].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
    td[3].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
    td[6].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
    td[9].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
  }

  function normalclass() {
    td[0].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
    td[3].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
    td[6].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
    td[9].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
  }

  if ($(window).width() < 512) normalclass(); /*This line couldn’t work.*/

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 512) normalclass();
    else waddonsclass();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You should look up how to use @media in css and see if that helps. If so you can do this without javascript, just in css

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function, the var has not yet been created. 
So to make it work: Put the var td in the functions 2 times.

```
<script>
  function waddonsclass() {
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    td[0].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
    td[3].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
    td[6].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
    td[9].className = "waddons-wsite-multicol-col";
  }

  function normalclass() {
   var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    td[0].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
    td[3].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
    td[6].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
    td[9].className = "wsite-multicol-col";
  }

  if ($(window).width() < 512) normalclass(); /*This line couldn’t work.*/

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 512) normalclass();
    else waddonsclass();
  });
</script>
```

Its ugly js. But this is the answer i guess. Cheers!

Comment: Why wouldn't the `td`s be defined inside the function? `td` is indeed within the lexical scope of each function there. Reselecting them would only be necessary if more get added between script execution and function execution.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a functioning snippet for using jQuery. I've cleaned up your code a bit. There's no need for two functions as you only need one and you can pass the single function has a handler to `$(window).resize(resized)`.

```js
function resized() {
  var css_class = $(this).width() < 512 ? 'wsite-multicol-col' : 'waddons-wsite-multicol-col';
  $('td:nth-child(3n+1)').addClass(css_class);
}

$(window).resize(resized);
resized();
```

```css
.wsite-multicol-col {
  background: blue;
}

.waddons-wsite-multicol-col {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, you can do it with CSS. However, I do not know of a way to add a specific class based on `:nth-child`.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 512px ) {
  td:nth-child(3n+1) {
    /* styles for < 512 screen width */
  }
}
@media screen and ( min-width: 512px ) {
  td:nth-child(3n+1) {
    /* styles for > 512 screen width */
  }
}
```